# Calculate difference of two LineString

Tags: java, geotools, linestring, differences, symmetric-difference

The tool I'm developing is written in Java with Spring Boot, using PostgreSQL as database (PostGIS extension). I also make use of GeoTools.

I want to calculate the geometrical difference between two LineString geometries, but I'm quite lost in this problem.

Perhaps it'd be better to draw an example.

The red LineString would be Trip 1:
[image]

The green LineString would be Trip 2:
[image]

What I want to get is the orange LineStrings (as MultiLineString or so):
[image]

The problem is that to get the difference between red and green lines I'd like to apply some kind of tolerance values, e.g. 5 meters, so that I can get rid of inaccuracies like this one (and consider them as lines that crosses the same path):
[image]

In PostGIS, there is a function called [ST_SymDIfference](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SymDifference.html), but there isn't tolerance parameter.

Is it possible to accomplish what I want?

**Edit**

@eth4io answer is the correct one. Since its based on PostGIS code, I'll write the Java code which replicates it:

```java
public Geometry calculateDiffs(final LineString pPlan, final LineString pRoute) {
    Double distance = 0.0002d;
    Geometry planBuffered = pPlan.buffer(distance);
    Geometry routeBuffered = pRoute.buffer(distance);
    Geometry intersection = routeBuffered.intersection(planBuffered);
    Geometry difference = pRoute.difference(intersection);
    return difference;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use buffer to implement something like tolerance for this probelm

Given two lines blue and green
[image: example of two lines]

code in PostGIS

```sql
with shared as (
  select st_intersection(st_buffer(blue.geometry, 0.05), st_buffer(green.geometry, 0.05)) as buffer
  from blue, green
)
select st_difference(blue.geometry, buffer) as geometry
from blue, green, shared;
```

Orange is the difference you want
[image: difference]

Note the magic number 0.05 used in the example is in degree, not a usual tolerance value.

Comment: I'll try to replicate your code in Java using GeoTools and I'll share the code